# The proof of $\chi_A:I\to \mathbb R$ is integrable $\iff $ $\chi_A:J\to \mathbb R$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying the integration on Jordan measurable sets.

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be bounded and $\chi_A$ be a characteristic function of $A$

Then, I want to prove that if $I\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $J\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ are intervals s.t. $A\subset I \subset J,$ then
\begin{align}
\chi_A: I\to \mathbb R \ \mathrm{is \ Riemann \ integrable \ on\ } I \iff  \chi_A : J\to \mathbb R \mathrm{\ is\ Riemann \ integrable\ on\ } J
\end{align}

For the proof of this, I think the theorem below is useful.

**Theorem**

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a interval and $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be bounded.

$f$ is integrable on $I$ if and only if for
all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition of $I$ s.t. $S(f,\Delta)-s(f,\Delta)<\epsilon$ where $S$ is the upper sum and $s$ is the lower sum.

---

Suppose $\chi_A : I\to \mathbb R$ is integrable on I.

Let $\epsilon>0.$

Then, from the integrability of $\chi_A: I\to \mathbb R$, there exists the partition of $I$, $\Delta=\{I_k\}_{k=1}^M$ s.t. $S(\chi_A, \Delta)-s(\chi_A, \Delta)<\epsilon.$

Then, I have to find the partition of $J$ s.t. $S(\chi_A, \Delta')-s(\chi_A, \Delta')<\epsilon \  ($or $a \cdot \epsilon \ (a>0)).$

I'm having difficulty in finding such $\Delta'.$

I'd like you to gime me any help.

(This is the step of defining the integral on Jordan measurable sets.)

---

Just so you know, the definition of the integrability of functions on a interval is here.

Let $I\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an interval.

$f:I\to \mathbb R$ is integrable on $I$ $\underset{\mathrm{def}}\iff$ $\overline{\displaystyle\int_I} f(x) dx=\underline{\displaystyle\int_I}f(x) dx,$ where $\overline{\displaystyle\int_I}$ is upper integral and $\underline{\displaystyle\int_I}$ is lower integral.

Comment: You can use the theorem that a bounded function is Riemann integrable if and only if its discontinuity set is of  measure zero. The indicator function is discontinuous only on the boundary $\partial A$. When $A$ is Jordan measurable, the boundary must be of content zero which implies measure zero. Depending on the inclusion $A \subseteq I \subseteq J$, the discontinuities lie on no more than  $\partial A \cup \partial I \cup \partial J$ which has measure zero.  If you want to prove this from first principles with Darboux sums see below.

Comment: In both directions consider suitable partitions whose associated upper and lower sums are the same, knowing that the intersection of two intervals is an interval and the difference of two intervals is the finite union of non-overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 1):

A partition $P$ of $J$ can be refined using the endpoints of $I$ to produce a partition $P'$. We then have $P' = P_1 \cup P_2$ where the interior of any subinterval in $P_1$ is disjoint from $I$ and the interior of any subinterval in $P_2$ is contained in $I$. Moreover $P_2$ is a partition of $I$.

We can decompose upper and lower Darboux sums as

$$S(\chi_A,P') =  S(\chi_A,P_1) +S(\chi_A,P_2), \quad  s(\chi_A,P') =  s(\chi_A,P_1) +s(\chi_A,P_2)$$

If $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable on $J$, then given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $$S(\chi_A,P) - s(\chi_A,P) < \epsilon$$

Since $P'$ is a refinement of $P$, we have $s(\chi_A,P) \leqslant s(\chi_A,P')\leqslant S(\chi_A,P')\leqslant S(\chi_A,P)$

Note that a difference of upper and lower Darboux sums is always nonnegative, and, hence,

$$S(\chi_A,P_2) - s(\chi_A,P_2) \leqslant S(\chi_A,P_1) - s(\chi_A,P_1) + S(\chi_A,P_2) - s(\chi_A,P_2)\\ = S(\chi_A,P') - s(\chi_A,P') \leqslant S(\chi_A,P) - s(\chi_A,P) < \epsilon$$

Therefore, $\chi_A$ is Riemann integrable on $I$ (since $P_2$ is a partition of $I$ satisfying the Riemann criterion ).

Try for yourself to prove that integrability on $I$ implies integrability on $J$.